# How to create selective output from a QGIS layer, using QGIS2leaf?

Tags: qgis, qgis2leaf

I want to create a web map on which only a selection of data from a layer is displayed. To the best of my knowledge the tool seems to output the full layer.

In Mapinfo I'd run a query to create a new table which would display only the selection of data I want. I've not done anything similar with QGIS - and I don't know if it would work if I did.

I realise I could pursue a non-elegant solution in the short term - extracting data from the layer and saving it as a new file... but there must be a more flexible/elegant way (because this layer would need to be updated each time the parent layer changed).

Comment: This is a good point to exported only selected features. I've created an issue for it and will implement it in one of the next releases! https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/issues/176

Comment: Great! Can I briefly take the opportunity to say what an excellent tool this is. Personally I'm able to undertake this process by hand, but I have colleagues who may just be converted to QGIS by this (and of course I'll not need to do it by hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your features by right-clicking the layer and selecting "Filter...". There you can enter a string much like the `WHERE` clause in SQL.

The same feature is available on the "General" tab of the Layer Properties dialog, where it is labeled as "Feature subset".

You can combine filters using AND, e.g.

```
"fid" IN (1, 2, 3) AND
"street" ILIKE 'electric%' AND
"foo" IS NOT NULL
```

These filters transfert into qgis2leaf and the resulting Leaflet layer only contains the selected features.

Comment: I was wondering about this. Is it possible to have more than one filter working at the same time (as would be possible with separate queries in Mapinfo)? More importantly, does this filtered dataset transfer into the leaflet map with qgis2leaf?

Comment: Yes, see my edits to the answer.

Comment: @user27285 Not sure how you intend to combine filters, but the typical SQL logical operators `AND` and `OR` are available. Also, you can add the same data source multiple times with different filters.

Comment: Thank you for these answers. Exactly what I wanted to know.